# Windows Service keep crashing with Faulting Module SHLWAPI.dll

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, 64-bit, windows-server-2012

I have a Windows Service running in "Local System account" context.

I can start the service successfully, but after a few minutes it crashes. I get following error in the event log

What could be the possible reason, and how to fix this issue?

```
Faulting application name: MyWindowsService.exe, version: 1.0.0.2993, time stamp: 0x554085eb
Faulting module name: SHLWAPI.dll, version: 6.3.9600.16384, time stamp: 0x521574db
Exception code: 0xc00000fd
Fault offset: 0x00005d66
Faulting process id: 0x14d4
Faulting application start time: 0x01d0830a94202cb3
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\MyProject\Etswap Workflow Polling Service\MyWindowsService.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\SHLWAPI.dll
Report Id: ff232358-eefe-11e4-94ea-08002787efe4
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Comment: Do you have any logging inside your code?

Comment: yes, we have logging enabled, and we are logging in the event viewer. But     the said error is logged in the Windows Application log and not in our Application's event log. That means, I can see the last successful message in application's log, and then the above message in Windows log.

Comment: It is a stackoverflow exception.  That's always a bug in your code, not in Windows.  You'll have to debug it.

Comment: this application is deployed on 4 other environments, and we are facing no such issue on any of them.. so wondering if there is something related to some setup or system configurations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, it was a bug in the application only.
it was a rare scenario which was going into a deadlock situation.

Fixed